# c# Inheritance, static to store globally

Tags: c#

any idea to simplify the code? Sorry, added, is web application,
example, I had an userID value that store when login, and I session the value, but the point is, I had so many class that will use the same variable for further checking, how can I reduce the code?

```
string xxx= session("UserID");

Logon.checkUser(xxx);
Attempt.Check(xxx);
NNN.Check(xxx);
yyy.dosomething(xxx);
```

I try inherit the class, but the value gone after go through the next class, unless need to pass in the value again.

I try static and inherit it, the value are remain at the base class and it work great which reduce the repeatative work , but it is ok to use static to store all the value? or there any better idea?

Comment: What sort of application are you talking about here? The mention of session makes me fear it's a web app of some kind, in which case, no, `static` is not right, because it'll break as soon as you get a second user connected.

Comment: You've said it *is* a web application. In which case, it sounds like it's already in the right place - in the session.

Comment: If there is any other way, to not to pass the parameter, but all class share the UserID in classes instead of passing in by parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Try a Utility Class

```
  public static class  HelperUtility
{
    public static  string GetUserId()
    {
        return Session["UserId"];
    }
}
```